# Blocking Awaitable instances with Duration.Inf, best practice?

Tags: scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

We knew this piece of code:

```
Await.result(someFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

If I put a finite value of duration say 3 seconds, once expired, it throws TimeOutException.

How about Duration.Inf, I am afraid the application hang. What is the best practice on using Duration.Inf?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best practice on using `Duration.Inf`?

The best practice would be to not block using `Await` at all, and use some sort of callback to handle the `Future` asynchronously, like `map`, `foreach`, `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, etc, depending on your use case.

If you must block using `Await` for whatever reason (there should be very few reasons to actually do this), you should set a finite `Duration` with a reasonable limit. For example, if you know that `someFuture` normally takes 5 seconds to complete, perhaps set the timeout to 10 seconds. Otherwise, the thread calling `Await` *can* hang forever if the `Future` does not complete.

Nothing good can come out of using `Duration.Inf`, unless you *want* the application to hang indefinitely waiting for a long overdue `Future`, and doing so is absolutely critical. But in general, it is better to let it crash than not respond at all.